# How to call a method when a particular validation fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-models

I'm checking the uniqueness of email for users as:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email
```

That's fine. But, I need to call a method when this particular validation fails.

Thus, How to call a method when a particular validation fails in rails model?!

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
after_validation :email_contains_errors

def email_contains_errors
  if self.email.errors.any?
    # do something
  end
end
```

Or if it must be triggered when it fails:

```
validate :email_contains_errors, :unless => lambda { self.email.errors.empty? }
```